# Indicate comment was flagged in flag history

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags

In the flag history a flag on a comment links to the original question - not the comment that was flagged.

I think that the flag history should clearly indicate that the flag was on a comment. Now it looks like I've flagged a perfectly valid question as rude or offensive, while it was a comment that was inappropriate.

Comment: +1,  but I asked for this first. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought it should have been asked for before, but I couldn't find it. Bad search skills today.